# Why hibernate retrieves the list before updating the entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, relationship, hibernate-mapping

Following is mapping

Inside A.class

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "aObj")
private List<B> listB;
```

Inside B.class

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
private A aObj;
```

I have 2 entities A and B. Entity A contains List as @OneToMany relationship and B contains reference to A as a bi-directional One-To-Many relationship. The insert operation works fine But when I try to update the record.

```
A a = repository.findById(1);
a.setName("Test Name");
repository.save(a);
```

The problem here is that hibernate executes one extra select all query for retrieving List.

The sequence is as follows

```
Hibernate: select query for A
Hibernate: select all query for B
Hibernate: update query for A
```

Now why that select all query matters here for B
I have defined lazy fetching strategy on both ends.

Comment: Post the mappings please

Comment: Please have a look. I have updated it

Comment: I would try removing the cascade

Comment: Try with `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}` instead of `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: I figured out the problem.
Besides OneToMany I was also using Size for validation purpose which is causing this extra select query. My List is as follows.
NotNull(message = "List cannot be left empty")
Size(min = 2, message = "List size should be of size 2")
OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "aObj")
private List<B> listB
..
Any solution for this? Without the Size annotation it is working fine;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "{your_var}", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<B> list;
```

And take care if you are using cascade:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {Cascade.PERSIST}, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<B> list;
```

This property act as a domino effect and try to persist or update List Objects in case the list isn't empty, I think that is not your approach in this case so don't use it

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look at the mapping